# Making a AI that guess the number that the user is thinking python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

The goal is that the user enters a number between 1-10 and AI tries to figure out what number the player picked.
For example I take the number: 6 and AI then tries to find out which number with 3 attempts.

AI learns which numbers are frequently chosen and tries them.

The problem is. I'm new to machine learning and thought this would be a good project to learn about machine learning. I can't find such a project anywhere and I don't know where to start. I've already asked this question on other platforms but it looks like nobody can help me.

I thought I use python, keras and tensorflow for that

**Has anyone done this before or know where it is?**

Thanks :)

Comment: And how do you see the interaction between your AI and the user. If AI just makes a guess and the user says yes/no, then there's no way that the machine learning will learn anything

Comment: Another setup - your AI makes a guess and the user says is it bigger/lower. Then there's a classical algorithm of binary search, which is already optimal and you don't need any machine learning

Comment: Even if you decide to attempt this, you need data to learn from. You need a lot of people to pick their number, so that some numbers might truly appear more frequent than the others. If you collect the data using a Python `random()`, then the distribution will be uniform, and again there's nothing to learn. The AI will be making random guesses

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you assume your user gives non-uniform distributed data.

However, this problem may not really related to ML.
One of the easy solutions is to let users choose, again and again, you collect the data. You will likely find a distribution that fits your data (if your user really does so). Then you can use that distribution to predict.

Take a look at [scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit)